# Parsing multiple URLS with retrofit

Tags: java, android, xml, rss, retrofit2

Building news feed app and currently using retrofit to fetch and parse RSS feeds. Though I have to create multiple retrofit objects and calls to be able to parse multiple URLS in one activity.

```
       //initialising retrofit
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(UrlsList.getBaseUrlsList().get(7))
            //converter XML
            .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    FeedChannelAPI feed = retrofit.create(FeedChannelAPI.class);

    Call<RssFeed> call = feed.getFeed(UrlsList.getRssUrlsList().get(7));

    //starting callbacks
    call.enqueue(new Callback<RssFeed>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<RssFeed> call, Response<RssFeed> response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: feed: " + response.body().toString());

            List<Item> mItems = response.body().getmChannel().getItems();

            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Server Response: " + response.toString());

            //initialise arraylist to add news to the class
            for (int i = 0; i < mItems.size(); i++) {
                XmlExtraction extractVerge = new XmlExtraction(mItems.get(i).getDescription(), "src=");
                List<String> postContent = extractVerge.start();
                news.add(new NewsClass(
                        mItems.get(i).getTitle(),
                        mItems.get(i).getPubDate(),
                        mItems.get(i).getLink(),
                        postContent.get(0),
                        response.body().getmChannel().getTitle()

                ));

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<RssFeed> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: Unable to retrieve RSS: " + t.getMessage());

        }

    });

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(UrlsList.getBaseUrlsList().get(13))
            //converter XML
            .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    feed = retrofit.create(FeedChannelAPI.class);

    call = feed.getFeed(UrlsList.getRssUrlsList().get(13));

    //starting callbacks
    call.enqueue(new Callback<RssFeed>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<RssFeed> call, Response<RssFeed> response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: feed: " + response.body().toString());

            List<Item> mItems = response.body().getmChannel().getItems();

            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Server Response: " + response.toString());

            //initialise arraylist to add news to the class
            for (int i = 0; i < mItems.size(); i++) {
                XmlExtraction extractVerge = new XmlExtraction(mItems.get(i).getDescription(), "img src=");
                List<String> postContent = extractVerge.start();
                news.add(new NewsClass(
                        mItems.get(i).getTitle(),
                        mItems.get(i).getPubDate(),
                        mItems.get(i).getLink(),
                        postContent.get(0),
                        response.body().getmChannel().getTitle()

                ));

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<RssFeed> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: Unable to retrieve RSS: " + t.getMessage());

        }

    });
```

I've been wondering is it possible to parse multiple base URLS.
Currently my interface looks like following

```
public interface FeedChannelAPI {

@GET
Call<RssFeed> getFeed(@Url String url);}
```

Is it possible to parse as an argument `List<String>` I've tried but the app kept crashing. Overall what I would like  to achieve is to be able with one retrofit object and one call parse multiple URLS. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no `parse()` command/code in your code. Moreover you did not tell what you want to parse out of that list.

Comment: Sorry, i paraphrase. Instead of  Call<RssFeed> getFeed(@Url String url); use Call<RssFeed> getFeed(@Url List<String>);

Comment: And?? What is the result of you doing so?